Have Karaites been able to muster a minyan?
According to legend, the Or Hachaim cursed the Karaites, because they tricked him into walking on a Mishneh Torah, that they would never be able to muster a minyan.
This apparently did happen in Turkey at the time - any time a Karaite would gain a new member, an old one would die.
Apparently the British Consul in Mandate Palestine James Finn wrote, when in 1852 twenty Karaite immigrantes arrived in Jerusalem and became deathly ill and quickly passed away, that "it was a judgement from Heaven on the Karaites that they were never able to muster a prayer quorum".
I've seen this mentioned in A Legacy of Leaders (The Bayar Edition by Yehuda Azoulay), as well as here (p. 16):

In 1741, the mayor of the Jerusalem demanded that the Jews pay an
inordinately high tax. An urgent meeting was organised by the resident
rabbonim. Since the Karaite shul was literally underground, it was
felt it would be the most unobtrusive place to hold the meeting. The
story is told that as Rav Chaim ben Atar (the Ohr Hachayim) walked
down the steps, he slipped and fainted. The Rabbis laid him on the
floor and tried to revive him and meanwhile the stone stair.
Where he had slipped was dislodged, revealing that underneath it,
there had been placed a volume of the Rambam’s Mishnah Torah. When the
Ohr Hachayim regained consciousness, he denounced the Karaites for
their flagrant disrespect, and decreed that they would be responsible
for the full tax demanded by the mayor. Furthermore, he cursed them
that they would never have a tenth man to make a minyan.
Although certain elements of the story are undoubtedly correct (the
British consul, James Finn, recorded a century later - in 1853 - that
“it was a judgement from Heaven on the Karaites that they were never
able to muster a prayer quorum”), the imposing of the full tax on the
Karaites would have been extremely unlikely given that their entire
community consisted of a handful of indigent individuals and there was
no expectation that it was going to grow. Another fascinating tale of
Karaite and Rabbinic Jews in Jerusalem emerges from a quite detailed
letter discovered in the Cairo genizoh. In 1053, a group of Jews left
Toledo in Spain, headed for the Holy Land. One of these couples -
Ibrahim ibn Fadanj and his wife - had originally been part of the
Rabbinite community and descendants of a distinguished family, but had
switched over to Karaism before their arrival in Eretz Yisroel.
Indeed, it is probable that this change had brought them to Jerusalem
in the first place, given that Jerusalem was a stronghold of Karaite
Judaism in the 11th century.
Having settled in Ramleh, an issue arose which would threaten their
marriage. As Ibn Fadanj’s brother was married to his wife’s sister,
they were forbidden by Karaite law to remain married, since Karaites
maintained that marriage made husband and wife into one literal unit,
thereby forbidding all their immediate relatives to one another. Ibn
Fadanj and his wife then moved to Jerusalem with their four children
and joined the Karaite community, but after two years the Karaite
elders discovered the matter of their forbidden marriage and ordered
them to divorce. At this point they decided to re-join the Rabbinite
community, in order to preserve their marriage

I am looking to substantiate this original story, this curse, this quote from James Finn, and if there is any evidence of this curse today. The latter seems unlikely (although there may be discussion as to why the curse has been lifted which will also be on topic!), so I am mainly hoping for the exact source of the quote from James Finn, and the original mention of the episode with the Ohr Hachaim Hakodesh.

Do they believe in minyan?

@shmosel not as a Torah obligation, but I believe some did adopt it as a custom

@Rabbi do we even believe it's a Torah obligation?

@DoubleAA what I meant was, because they do not view it as a Torah obligation, they do not follow it. Whether we do or not is irrelevant

They have quaroms in their current synagogues ,in California and in even the Jerusalem seems like the have had more than 10 ...https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/karaite-judaism/

Here's the Finn quote, from his book Stirring Times, Vol. II, p. 57:

"A question had arisen in the Seraglio, after the arrival of Yakoob Pashà, about the Karaite Jews-- whether or not they were Russian subjects, and therefore liable to expulsion on account of the declaration on war between Turkey and Russia. They had never been considered as Russian subjects, and their number was so insignificant that they had been hitherto overlooked. It was always asserted of them by the other (Rabbinical) Jews that it was judgement from heaven on the Karaites that they were never able to muster a minyan, i.e. a quorum of ten adults of families, for forming a lawful congregation according to Jewish ordinance. They did not amount to that number, but then they did not care about this Talmudical number of ten being necessary, any more than for any other Rabbinical rule.

Near as I can tell, the story first appeared in print in the book Sha'arei Yerushalayim by the 19th century journalist Moshe Reisher, p. 54a:

"מעשה בירושלים בזמן הרב הקדוש בעל אור החיים הנה בירושלי' היו קראים הרבה. הם הצדוקים אמונתם ידועה לכל כי הם אינם מאמינים בדברי חז"ל רק בתורת משה גם בו הולכים מארחות עקלקלות כפי דעתם הכזבה. פעם א' גבר לחץ הממשלה על היהודים בירושלים בשומו עליהם מס כבד מנשוא. אז צוה הרבה הנ"ל על המקהלה. להתאסף בסתר בבית תפלת הקראים למען לא ישמע הדבר. (כי עד היום היא מתחת לקרקע). ולראות איזה עצה ולהתפלל אל ה'. ברדת הרב הקדוש הנ"ל בגר' המעלות לבוא אל האסיפה התעלף פתאום ורגליו כשלו. ויתמהו האנשי' איש אל רעהו. ויאמרו אין זאת כ"א רוח רעה השוכן פה הדביקתהו. ויבוקש הדבר בחפרה חיש מתחת לגרם המעלות וימצא כי טמנו שם הקראים את ספרי רבינו משה בר מיימון ז"ל למען הבזותם ולדרוך עלימו ויכשיעם לשלם את מכסת המס על פני כלה. גם קללם לבלי היות בינימו מנין י' אנשים כשנולד אחד או כשבא אחד מעיר אחרת מת אחד מהם. הנה זה כשלשים שנה באו כעשרים משפחות קראים ממדינתם להתגורר בירושלי' ועדת הקראים הקטנה שמחה והריעה לקראת בואם בהמלא עתה מספרם. אך ששונ' נהפך להם לאבל ולשממת נפש. כי כמעט הגיעו הבאים לגור לשער ירושלים ותחל המגפה להשחית בהם עדי מתו כל האנשים טרם הגיעם לפתח בית הקראים והנשארים מתו בבית. עדי גם היום לא נמלא עוד המנין בינימו."

Mordechai Spielman copied this story from Sha'arei Yerushalayim in his 1905 edition of Rabbi Chaim Horowitz's book Chibat Yerushalayim, p. 47b but noted that he heard that it happened in the time of Rabbi Yaakov Chagiz (can be found on Otzar Hachochmah).

This makes sense that it would have to do with Russian/Crimean Karaites who were small in number. Whereas in my answer I was discussing the Karaites from Egypt, who are much more numerous and have a stronger Jewish tradition

Even though this is a quote from Finn about Karaites and curses, it does not match the sources I have brought (it's not about anybody dying). Do you have any information as to why that may be? Also, the story about the Ohr Hachaim takes place in Jerusalem, which differs from the sources in the OP, so same question?

@RabbiKaii for some reason my devices aren't able to open quickly the PDF you linked. Could you copy the relevant text as a comment or post a picture of it in your question?

@Harel13 done.. Re-read the Azoulay version, and it mentions "Turkish mayor", so I assumed it was in Turkey, so ignore that. It was in Jerusalem

There's a Karaite synagogue/Museum in Jerusalem that I've visited. And while they weren't holding services while I was there, there are a lot of pictures of them definitely having a minyan
The Karaites in the US have a congregation in Daily City in California and I believe they have a minyan, and they pray with Reform Jews when their synagogue is under construction.
Other than this vague legend, and the evidence some died in Turkey, I don't think anyone with eyes who lives next to Karaites would believe such a curse is in effect.

It could be that these Karaites aren't following real karaitism and therefore the curse doesn't apply to them. Ie. They don't follow everything even if it's in the Torah rather they pick and choose like reform etc.

When I was in Jerusalem I was advised by the Karaite Synagogue's caretaker that they didn't have services then because it was during the week but that every now and again they would hold services when the rest of the Karaites come down from Ramla and it would be a few Shabatot in the future. Since my wife was with me they advised me that if my wife was on her period she would need to be prepared to be sitting separate in the services. So I'm not sure I buy your argument they aren't following real Karaitism

that shows they kept that specific law. Again I still think that they don't practice it properly and therefore the curse doesn't apply.

@Moishe this is neither here nor there. Not surprisingly, and ironically, the Karaites have internal machlokes and different "traditions"

@RabbiKaii so much for being a karait lol

@Moishe modern historians think that Karaism rose out of a mixture of different medieval marginal Jewish sects, so it's quite natural that there are different opinions and traditions. Likewise, what is termed "Rabbinic" Judaism evolved from different schools such as Beit Hillel, Beit Shammai, batei midrash of other sages, etc, and they did not always agree on everything.

The key point of the Karaites was that they disagreed on what keys should be used to interpret the Torah. Do the keys lie within the Oral Torah or that a made-up concept that gives a select class of saves authority over the rest of the Jews? Perhaps the keys lie elsewhere.

@RabbiKaii Why traditions with quotation marks? The movement rose over a thousand years ago, likely (as I noted in my comments above) out of even older sects. Why would they not have varying traditions, much like Orthodox Jews?

@Harel13 To highlight the word, not invalidate it. The point is that it is ironic that they have traditions but deny that there is an Oral Tradition. I think that is quite a self evident irony, but noted that it's a rather moot point and has a rather down to earth response.

I don't think you should even be putting it in quotes. They don't deny everything in the orap tradition, they deny the authority and all inclusiveness that Rabbinic Jews put on the oral law. They are willing to accept aspects of it on a case by case basis
